How do I run a task on poweroff, but not on reboot, before a mount point is unmounted?
I have configured /etc/fstab to auto-mount an NFS share on startup;
I have also configured rsnapshot to backup some crucial system data (/home, /etc, ...) to the same NFS share by running rsnapshot -V alpha.
I would like to schedule a backup task that will run automatically under the following confitions:

The system is going down for poweroff
The system is not going down for reboot (it would be pretty annoying to wait for a backup to complete every time I'm simply rebooting the machine)

How may I go about doing this? It would be great if the solution would work for any /etc/fstab-mounted filesystem, and not just for NFS shares.

After putting toghether many bits and pieces from the internet, here's what I came up with.
This will work for any /etc/fstab-mounted filesystem, and not just for NFS shares.
Preface: the idea is to get a systemd service to run the backup command on poweroff.
What my research has taught me is that:

It's hard to latch the service to the right point in the poweroff / reboot chain if you're approaching the problem in terms of "order in which services go down in the poweroff / reboot chain"; there's just too much to keep track of. The trick here, is to approach the problem in terms of "order in which services go up in the startup chain", and to latch a oneshot service right after the target mount point has gone up, at the same time marking it as active using RemainAfterExit=true and providing it with an ExecStop action which will be "naturally" triggered when the system is going down, just right before the target mount point is unmounted.
There's no super-clean way to determine if the system is going down for poweroff or for reboot; however, this can be done reliably by checking which systemd special targets are active during the poweroff / reboot sequence; in this case, poweroff.target will be active only in case the system is going down for poweroff.

So, putting everything toghether, this can be done by adding the following to /etc/systemd/system/rsnapshot.service (the name of the file and the Description and ExecStop fields, of course, may be adjusted, and the After field must be adjusted based on the system; see below for how to go about finding out the name of the mount unit to latch to; make sure the file is owned by root:root and has 644 / -rw-r--r-- permissions):
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

[Service]
ExecStop=sh -c 'systemctl list-jobs | grep -q "poweroff.target.*start" && rsnapshot -V alpha'
RemainAfterExit=true
TimeoutStopSec=infinity

[Unit]
After=mnt-nas-backup.mount
Description=rsnapshot

To find out the name of the mount unit to latch to (filesystems mounted via /etc/fstab will start with mnt-*):
systemctl list-units --type=mount

Once done, run sudo systemctl enable --now update.service to enable the service.
TimeoutStopSec=infinity is obviously needed in case of a backup, but it can be changed in case you want to use this for something else.
